# How to set restype in function to pointer to object of a class in python with ctypes?

Tags: python, c++, numpy

I need to pass to the demodulateDoubleMatrix the demodulator object, 2-dim numpy array and it's shape. I don't know how to set first argument to be a reference to Demodulator object?

```
def __init__(self):
    array_1d_double = npct.ndpointer(dtype=numpy.float64, ndim=1, flags='C_CONTIGUOUS')
    array_2d_double = npct.ndpointer(dtype=numpy.float64, ndim=2, flags='C_CONTIGUOUS')
    self.lib = npct.load_library("libdemodulator", ".")
    self.demodulator = None
    self.lib.demodulateDoubleMatrix.argtypes = [ctypes.re, array_2d_double, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int]
    self.lib.demodulateDoubleMatrix.restype = None
```

My library have this interface

```
extern "C" {
    Demodulator<double>* Demodulator_new_double(int rows, int cols);

    double * demodulateDoubleMatrix(Demodulator<double>* demodulator, double * input, int rows, int columns);
}
```